# "Cannot use import statement outside a module" and "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" when importing a class

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to import a class into my "main.js" file. Here is a minified version of my code.

```
// "extended.js" file

export default class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.prop = "Hello"
    console.log(this.prop)
  }
}


// "main.js" file

window.onload = function () {
  import Test from "./extended"
  new Test()
}
```

The main.js file is the frontend JavaScript file for my Express app so it is stored in the "public" folder. When you load the page the initial error that occurs is "Cannot use import statement outside a module". I've done research on my own and multiple people have stated that using
`type="module"` for the "main.js" script tag will resolve the issue. When I did that the error changed to "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier". Is there something I'm missing about how to use ES6 modules and classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only import at the top level - it can't be done inside a block. Change

```
window.onload = function () {
  import Test from "./extended"
  new Test()
}
```

to

```
import Test from "./extended"
window.onload = function () {
  new Test()
};
```

Though, I'd also suggest not creating classes for side-effects - if you just want the class to *do* something, but not to *return* something useful, use a plain function instead.

```
export default () => {
  const prop = "Hello";
  console.log(prop);
};
```

Comment: That resolved the issue but I am now getting a new error, "GET http://localhost:5000/extended net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)". I'm guessing this has something to do with the server. I was already using "express.static()" so I'm not sure what's happening here.

Comment: Did you mean to import `extended.js`, and not just `extended`?

Comment: That resolved the issue, thank you! I used the autocomplete feature so I didn't think much of it.